# How to use Autofill/Filldown with a range of values

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying to get Excel to apply a formula over a set of columns and then extend the pattern across the entire set of rows.
This has led to the following code:

```
For i = 0 To avgsheetNames.Count - 1
If Contains(CStr(avgsheetNames(i)), "Scores") = True Then
    With mainWorkBook.Worksheets(avgsheetNames(i))
        strFormulas(1) = "=SUM(Aggregated_Internal_Scores!I2:I7)/6"
        strFormulas(2) = "=SUM(Aggregated_Internal_Scores!J2:J7)/6"
        strFormulas(3) = "=SUM(Aggregated_Internal_Scores!K2:K7)/6"
        strFormulas(4) = "=SUM(Aggregated_Internal_Scores!L2:L7)/6"
        strFormulas(5) = "=SUM(Aggregated_Internal_Scores!M2:M7)/6"
        strFormulas(6) = "=SUM(Aggregated_Internal_Scores!N2:N7)/6"
        
        strFormulas2(1) = "=SUM(Aggregated_Internal_Scores!I8:I13)/6"
        strFormulas2(2) = "=SUM(Aggregated_Internal_Scores!J8:J13)/6"
        strFormulas2(3) = "=SUM(Aggregated_Internal_Scores!K8:K13)/6"
        strFormulas2(4) = "=SUM(Aggregated_Internal_Scores!L8:L13)/6"
        strFormulas2(5) = "=SUM(Aggregated_Internal_Scores!M8:M13)/6"
        strFormulas2(6) = "=SUM(Aggregated_Internal_Scores!N8:N13)/6"

        mainWorkBook.Worksheets(avgsheetNames(i)).Range("C2:H2").Formula = strFormulas
        mainWorkBook.Worksheets(avgsheetNames(i)).Range("C3:H3").Formula = strFormulas2
        mainWorkBook.Worksheets(avgsheetNames(i)).Range("C2:H3").AutoFill Destination:=mainWorkBook.Worksheets(avgsheetNames(i)).Range("C2:H32")
        
    End With
End If
```

As you can see I have tried to provide the pattern I am going for where the values extracted from the "Aggregated_Internal_Scores" sheet should follow the pattern `I2:I7` > `I8:I13` > `I14:I19` and so on.

However, when the macro has been executed what I get is `I2:I7` > `I8:I13` > `I4:I9` > `I10:I15`?

It seems Excel is taking the block C2:H3 as the pattern and just incrementing by 2 at the start of every block.

Can you anyone explain where I have gone wrong and how I can specify that I want the extraction of sheet values to follow a certain pattern?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
mainWorkBook.Worksheets(avgsheetNames(i)).Range("C2:H32").Formula = "=SUM(INDEX(Aggregated_Internal_Scores!I:I,(ROW($ZZ1)-1)*6+2):INDEX(Aggregated_Internal_Scores!I:I,(ROW($ZZ1)-1)*6+7))/6"
```

Replace everything inside the `If` with that.

---

If one has Office 365 with dynamic array formula then use:

```
mainWorkBook.Worksheets(avgsheetNames(i)).Range("C2:H32").Formula2 = "=SUM(INDEX(Aggregated_Internal_Scores!I:I,SEQUENCE(6,,(ROW($ZZ1)-1)*6+2))/6"
```

Comment: Thank you sincerely for the assistance. I have implemented your solution within the `If` block however, it seems to be producing an application-defined or object-defined error?  Do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: @TheHolyPebble sorry, I had a typo.  see edit.

Comment: Worked an absolute treat, thank you again!

Comment: Apologies I don't know if you will see this but what if I wanted to capture the values of every other row in the range of `I2` to `I7`?
After some tinkering I understand `INDEX(Aggregated_Internal_Scores!N:N,(ROW()*2))` captures the values from every other row but I can't seem to work out how to specify an upper limit so I can calculate an average of 3 values.
Perhaps it would be easier to just extract every other row to a new spreadsheet?
Would appreciate more of that glorious wisdom!

Comment: New question get new posts.  Please post a new question.  It is possible to do what you want. But too long for comments.

Comment: No worries at all, I have posted a new question at the following link. Thanks again!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66447045/extracting-alternating-values-across-worksheet-in-order-to-calculate-average