# Extracting alternating values across worksheet in order to calculate average

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to extract values from alternating rows up to a specified upper limit in order to calculate the average.
So far, I have the following code:

```
mainWorkBook.Worksheets(avgsheetNames(i)).Range("C2:H32").Formula = "=SUM(INDEX(Aggregated_Internal_Scores!I:I,(ROW($ZZ1)-1)*6+2):INDEX(Aggregated_Internal_Scores!I:I,(ROW($ZZ1)-1)*6+7))/6"
```

However, I would like to modify this so that in the range of `I2` to `I7` the values from `I2`, `I4` and `I6` are obtained for further calculations. It would be desirable to be able to apply this to the range as specified `"C2:H32"`.
Any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: will it always be the 1st,3rd, and 5th in each block?

Comment: It will indeed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If non Office 365:

```
mainWorkBook.Worksheets(avgsheetNames(i)).Range("C2:H32").FormulaArray = "=SUM(INDEX(INDEX(Sheet1!I:I,(ROW($ZZ1)-1)*6+2):INDEX(Sheet1!I:I,(ROW($ZZ1)-1)*6+7),N(IF({1},{1,3,5}))))/3"
```

Office 365:

```
mainWorkBook.Worksheets(avgsheetNames(i)).Range("C2:H32").Formula2 = "=SUM(INDEX(Aggregated_Internal_Scores!I:I,SEQUENCE(3,,(ROW($ZZ1)-1)*6+2,2))/3"
```

Comment: Thank you, that has cleared it up beautifully. Ticket to Hogwarts should be on the way because you're a wizard Scott. Have a good one!